# Set initial position in readline

Tags: linux, bash, readline

I am trying to make an iterative script in bash that takes the readline command as input.
I would like to know how I can change the position at the start of the command.

I've tried `READLINE_POINT=<num>`, but it doesn't work.

I have only achieved it by creating a keybinding, but I don't know how to call it automatically at the beginning of the `read`.

I have tried this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
x()(
    bind '"\C-j:"READLINE_POINT=4"'

    READLINE_POINT=5 # This does not work.

    read -rei 0123456789
)

x
```

But olny when I press `C-j` the cursor jump to position `4`.

I would like it to start directly at that position without pressing anything.

Any idea how to make it automatic when starting the `read`?

Comment: _"**READLINE_POINT** The position of the insertion point in the Readline line buffer, for use with ‘bind -x’"_ I don't think that you can use it outside of a `bind` command

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#index-set_002dmark-_0028C_002d_0040_0029) is what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I also think that using keybinding is not the correct approach, but I can't think of any other way. "set-mark" is also not working for me as it is used to set a mark to return to later, but requires user action.  What I look for is more to start directly in a specific position.